# Plotting data grouped by pairs of variables

Tags: r, plot

I have a large set of data like this consisting of the following variables.

```
Field    Country    AgeRange    Score    Test
```

I would like to barplot the average score of each group of all population grouped by Field and AgeRange. That is, I'd like something like this.

[image]

Note that variable AgeRange takes one of those 3 values, not the exact age of each participant.

I have no problem to group the data as needed. For example, by doing

```
aggr_data = aggregate(data, by=list(data$Field, data$AgeRange), FUN=mean)
```

I get the data grouped the way I needed, with a Score average associated to each Field-AgeRange pair. The problem is that I can't find a straightforward way to get a barplot from those values in which the y-axis corresponds to the obtained score, and the x-axis to each pair.

I think I could just grab each of the subsets I'm interested in, like so

```
young_cs = subset(data, Field=="CompSci" & AgeRange=="18-35")
m_young_cs = mean(young_cs[,"Score"])
mid_cs = subset(data, Field=="CompSci" & AgeRange=="36-53")
m_mid_cs = mean(mid_cs[,"Score"])
```

and then plot all the obtained means, but this is obviously very time-consuming. Is there a simpler, faster way to do this?

Here's a small random sample of the data.

```
Field        Country    AgeRange    Score    Test
Psychology   US         18-35       4.2      A
Psychology   US         18-35       3.1      C
Psychology   US         18-35       5.2      B
Psychology   US         36-53       4.7      A
Psychology   US         36-53       3.5      A
Psychology   US         54+         3.1      B
Psychology   US         54+         2.2      B
Psychology   US         54+         6.7      C
Psychology   US         54+         5.1      C
CompSci      US         18-35       5.2      B
CompSci      US         18-35       7.4      C
CompSci      US         18-35       6.1      A
CompSci      US         36-53       7.7      A
CompSci      US         36-53       8.1      A
CompSci      US         54+         8.2      B
CompSci      US         54+         7.7      B
CompSci      US         54+         6.9      A
CompSci      US         54+         9.0      C
Mathematics  US         18-35       6.2      B
Mathematics  US         18-35       6.4      A
Mathematics  US         18-35       7.1      A
Mathematics  US         36-53       8.7      A
Mathematics  US         36-53       9.4      A
Mathematics  US         54+         7.2      C
Mathematics  US         54+         6.1      B
Mathematics  US         54+         6.5      C
Mathematics  US         54+         7.0      C
```

Comment: this is not direct answer, but may be melting the data using `reshape2` and using `ggplot2` package?

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I'm not very familiar with those.

Comment: you should start by providing some data. ( a reproducible example).

Comment: can you give us dput() of above data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
#dummay data
field=c("P","C","M")
agerange=c(18,36,54)
score=rnorm(27, 7)
test=c("A","B","C")

df<-data.frame(field=rep(field, each=9),agerange= as.factor(rep(agerange,each=3, times=9)), score=score,test=rep(test, 9))

p<-ggplot(df, aes(x=field,y=score, fill=agerange))
p+geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")

#or
p+stat_summary(fun.y = "mean",geom = "bar", position="dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: It's weird, but I'm getting the same set of bars for every Field. I'll check if I made any mistake.

Comment: Found my mistake. My dataset is actually a little more complex so I needed to specify different step sizes in the frame. This answer requires less external libraries, and it came first, so I guess it deserves the accept.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

# a faceting approach
df2 <- ddply(df, .(Field, AgeRange), summarise, mscore = mean(Score))
ggplot(df2, aes(x=AgeRange, y = mscore, fill = AgeRange)) + geom_bar( stat = "identity" ) +
       facet_wrap(~Field)

# good enough?
```

[image]

```
    df <- structure(list(field = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), class = "factor", .Label = c("C", 
"M", "P")), agerange = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("18", "36", 
"54"), class = "factor"), score = c(7.30127138725929, 7.37770686922096, 
7.41317998674043, 6.64841878521039, 7.86711279540953, 7.17048025193224, 
8.44148594576163, 8.13949581473566, 6.30312423530373, 6.78529906805563, 
8.60960304217661, 7.08300936020387, 7.33518750196135, 7.29903060579703, 
7.81598828814603, 6.51481883845345, 6.85779851460457, 8.5001156704776, 
7.90225168492658, 6.57536590278191, 6.01020914251986, 7.28458327350041, 
7.07419918080273, 8.93252585403122, 6.54527682832174, 6.35152240141314, 
6.75924970388344, 7.30127138725929, 7.37770686922096, 7.41317998674043, 
6.64841878521039, 7.86711279540953, 7.17048025193224, 8.44148594576163, 
8.13949581473566, 6.30312423530373, 6.78529906805563, 8.60960304217661, 
7.08300936020387, 7.33518750196135, 7.29903060579703, 7.81598828814603, 
6.51481883845345, 6.85779851460457, 8.5001156704776, 7.90225168492658, 
6.57536590278191, 6.01020914251986, 7.28458327350041, 7.07419918080273, 
8.93252585403122, 6.54527682832174, 6.35152240141314, 6.75924970388344, 
7.30127138725929, 7.37770686922096, 7.41317998674043, 6.64841878521039, 
7.86711279540953, 7.17048025193224, 8.44148594576163, 8.13949581473566, 
6.30312423530373, 6.78529906805563, 8.60960304217661, 7.08300936020387, 
7.33518750196135, 7.29903060579703, 7.81598828814603, 6.51481883845345, 
6.85779851460457, 8.5001156704776, 7.90225168492658, 6.57536590278191, 
6.01020914251986, 7.28458327350041, 7.07419918080273, 8.93252585403122, 
6.54527682832174, 6.35152240141314, 6.75924970388344), test = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L
), class = "factor", .Label = c("A", "B", "C"))), .Names = c("field", 
"agerange", "score", "test"), row.names = c(NA, -81L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This seems to do the job, but I get the bars stacked, even if I pass position="dodge".

Comment: if you get bars stacked, you are not doing what I have done, did you read the `ddply` line?

Comment: Yep. I had to adapt it a little to the real thing because the data I presented was simplified to illustrate the problem, so most probably I've made a mistake.

Comment: Got it. I had written x=Field in the aes parameter of the ggplot.